# how to create and implementing numeric key pad in android

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-keypad

I have created a class which generates buttons runtime and i want to implement that class as key pad in specific edit text field how can i do that. code of my class is given below

```
public class KeyboardView extends View
{

    LinearLayout verticalLinearLayout, horizontalLinearLayout;
    Button button, btnZero, btnPoint, btnDone;




    public KeyboardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public KeyboardView(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public KeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int i) {
        super(context, attributeSet, i);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public LinearLayout addView(){
        verticalLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        verticalLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            horizontalLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {

                button = new Button(getContext());
                button.setText(String.valueOf(count++));
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ((Button)v).getText();
                    }
                });
                horizontalLinearLayout.addView(button);

            }
            verticalLinearLayout.addView(horizontalLinearLayout);
        }

        horizontalLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());

        btnZero = new Button(getContext());
        btnZero.setText("0");
        horizontalLinearLayout.addView(btnZero);

        btnPoint = new Button(getContext());
        btnPoint.setText(".");
        horizontalLinearLayout.addView(btnPoint);

        btnDone = new Button(getContext());
        btnDone.setText("Done");
        horizontalLinearLayout.addView(btnDone);

        verticalLinearLayout.addView(horizontalLinearLayout);

        return verticalLinearLayout;

    }


    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }

    public Button getBtnZero() {
        return btnZero;
    }

    public Button getBtnPoint() {
        return btnPoint;
    }

    public Button getBtnDone() {
        return btnDone;
    }
}
```

I want to implement this class as keypad in some specific edit text views please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow 2 links. such as

number 1#:  [Creating a Numeric Keypad with GridLayout](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677)

and number 2# [Introduction to Android development : TouchCalculator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104931/Introduction-to-Android-development-TouchCalculato)

I expected you will be help from those links. Best of luck!

Comment: But i am using class file as view and i want that as real key pad appears in front of us